# Generating Tree structure from Java Hashmap

Tags: java, json, tree, hashmap, parent-child

I currently have a class with several attributes describing a certain type of object in my system. This class is known as `EnrollmentInfo`.

I also have a hashmap that is structured as follows;

```
HashMap<EnrolmentInfo, List<EnrolmentInfo>> devices = new HashMap<>();
```

As it can be seen, the value properties in this hashmap contain an ArrayList of the EnrollmentInfo class type.
To provide some context, this hashmap is used to hold the parent nodes and associated child nodes of a tree structure as key, value pairs.

I generated this hashmap by traversing and extracting details from a child/parent table such as the following:

```
Child : Parent
    1 : 0
    2 : 0
    3 : 2
    4 : 0
    5 : 4
    6 : 4
    7 : 1
    8 : 6
```

The code for extracting the parents and children and putting them into the HashMap is as follows:

```
        // Extracts the parents and assigns them to the key values
        for (EnrolmentInfo enrolmentInfo : enrolmentInfos) {
            Integer nodeParentId = enrolmentInfo.getParentId();
            EnrolmentInfo parentEnrolmentInfo = dms.getDevice(nodeParentId).getEnrolmentInfo();
            devices.put(parentEnrolmentInfo, new ArrayList<EnrolmentInfo>());
        }
        // Extracts the children and assigns them to the children arraylist of each associated parent.
        for (EnrolmentInfo enrolmentInfo : enrolmentInfos) {
            int nodeId = enrolmentInfo.getId();
            Integer parentId = enrolmentInfo.getParentId();
            EnrolmentInfo nodeEnrolmentInfo = dms.getDevice(nodeId).getEnrolmentInfo();
            for (Map.Entry<EnrolmentInfo, List<EnrolmentInfo>> parentDevice : devices.entrySet()) {
                if (parentDevice.getKey().getId() == parentId) {
                    parentDevice.getValue().add(nodeEnrolmentInfo);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

My issue now is to compose this hashmap into an actual tree structure such that it can be compiled into a human-readable form via a JSON library.

More specifically how can a nested tree structure be generated based on the HashMap mentioned above?

**EDIT**:
Shown below is an example structure of the kind of JSON format I'm expecting at the end.

```
{
    "id" : 0,
    "children" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "children" : [
                {
                    "id" : 7,
                    "children" : []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "children" : [
                {
                    "id" : 3,
                    "children" : []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : 4,
            "children" : [
                {
                    "id" : 5,
                    "children" : []
                },
                {
                    "id" : 6,
                    "children" : [
                        {
                            "id" : 8,
                            "children" : []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**EDIT**:
So far I've created a bean class that is as follows:

```
public class DeviceHierarchyNode implements Serializable {
@ApiModelProperty(name = "id", value = "ID of the node generated. Same as Device ID",
        required = true)
private int id;

@ApiModelProperty(name = "label", value = "Device name as suggested by the user.",
        required = true)
private String label;

@ApiModelProperty(name = "children", value = "List of child devices associated with device if any",
        required = true)
private List<DeviceHierarchyNode> children;
```

My plan is to use this to create the final nested structure.

Comment: Tree could be represented on many different ways in `JSON`. For example: property is a parent id and value is array of primitives. Example payload could look like this: `{"0":[1,2,4], "1":[7], "2":[3], "4":[5,6]}`. Is this what do you want to achieve? Do I understand you properly?

Comment: Hi @MichałZiober I updated the answer to showcase what kind of final JSON output I'm expecting at the end

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service. We can however help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please edit your question to a much more narrowly focused problem, and show what you tried.

Comment: @Bohemian nowhere in my question had I asked for code. Nevertheless, I edited the question to provide a better context to what I'm trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: hacky.

Could you create a node type that wraps your underlying:

```
public class EnrolmentInfoNode {
    private EnrolmentInfo info;
    private List<EnrolmentInfoNode> children;

    public EnrolmentInfoNode(EnrolmentInfo contents) {
        this.info = contents;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + info.getId();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        EnrolmentInfoNode other = (EnrolmentInfoNode) obj;
        if (info.getId() != other.info.getId())
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public void addChild(EnrolmentInfoNode child) {
        if (children == null) {
            children = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        children.add(child);
    }
}
```

And then re-map thus:

```
    Map<EnrolmentInfo, EnrolmentInfoNode> nodeMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (Entry<EnrolmentInfo, List<EnrolmentInfo>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        for (EnrolmentInfo child : entry.getValue()) {
            EnrolmentInfoNode childNode = nodeMap.computeIfAbsent(child, EnrolmentInfoNode::new);

            nodeMap.computeIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), EnrolmentInfoNode::new)
                   .addChild(childNode);
        }
    }
```

Assuming you know node 0 is the parent:

```
    String json = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting()
                                   .create()
                                   .toJson(nodeMap.get(enrolmentInfo0));

    System.out.println(json);
```

If you don't, you can add a "parentNode" field to the `EnrolmentInfoNode` and then scan the node map to find the first one that has a null parent (therefore, root), and you're off to the races.